# Best way to compile a LaTeX project

Tags: compiling, build-system

Quite long time ago I was extensively using LaTeX with a `Makefile` that I have found on internet. This allowed me to automatically build/rebuild my project as many time as it was needed to get everything in place. Of course it also took care of the bibliography and the conversion of the `jpg` figures to `eps`. At the end, the `dvi` was translated to `ps` then to `pdf`.

It was quite easy because I simply had to configure my text editor (Vim) to use this `Makefile`.

Nowadays things have changed a lot and people tend to use scripts like `latexmk` that I don't know. Also it seems simpler to directly use `pdflatex` with viewers like `Sumatra` instead of regular `dvi` viewers.

What would be the most common method to build a whole LaTeX project in one step that includes the following elements?

- LaTeX files
- bibliography
- images (jpg, pdf, eps)
- code (c, php, ...)
- output from scripts (Matlab/Octave, Perl, ...)

Comment: latexmk will handle points 1 and 2 natively. If you use pdflatex on any modern TeX installation, point 3 is handled automatically (pdflatex will read PDF and JPG natively, and the epstopdf package is normally automatically loaded and handles EPS). Points 4 and 5 could be handled by the [listings](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings) package, but that won't run the scripts or programs on its own. So you could use a makefile to update output from point 5, and let latexmk and your document handle points 1-4.

Comment: Depending on your security concerns, you can enable spawning processes from within a TeX run to have scripts execute directly. The rest as already noted is pretty easy to script with `latexmk` or one of the alternatives (`rubber`, `arara`, ...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the meantime I have found a solution that is robust and that involves:

- A Docker image
- A GitHub repository
- A CI such as TravisCI
- A Makefile

One minimal example would be https://github.com/heig-vd-tin/refcard

A `Makefile` allow to use the Docker image to build the project

```
# Sed replacement for WSL
PWD!=pwd | sed 's/^\/mnt//'
DOCKER=docker run -it -v "$(PWD):/srv" -w=/srv nowox/latex:1.1

all: main.tex
    $(DOCKER) latexmk -pdf -xelatex $<

clean:
    $(DOCKER) latexmk -C

.PHONY: clean
```

The `.travis.yml` file will build the project at each commit:

```
sudo: required
language: latex
services: docker

before_install:
  - docker pull nowox/latex:1.1

script:
  - make
```